# Multilingual text search from MongoDB to Elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, solr, elasticsearch

I have multilingual data in MongoDB  with format like

```
"name":{
  "en" :  "dog",
  "fr" : "chien"
},"description" :{ 
}
```

I am concerned about text search, i.e user should be able to locate the same object with text search  like `"dog"` or `"chien"` (or their substrings). 
I am looking at several full text search engine like elasticsearch ,solr and sphinxsearch, and at first glance elasticsearch looks promising. Is the above a bad structure and is there obvious advantage of the other engines that would matters? And how would one implement such a search in elasticsearch?

Comment: You don't seem to have weird requirements, probably not enough information to judge. I'd suggest to play around a little and judge yourself what you like.

Answer (score 1):

Solr and ElasticSearch both are built on top of Apache Lucene, and both will provide the functionality you want.
I have not used Elastic Search, hence giving an overview based on my experience with Solr, but I am sure the same can be seamlessly transitioned to Elastic Search as well.

1. You will need to import and index your mongodb data into Solr . This is easily doable by running Solr, and using its rest api .
   You can also use 10gen mongo-connector : https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector which imports your mongodb records into Solr.
   There are many other ways to import your mongodb data into Solr, including writing your own scripts in language of your choice.
2. You need to define schema defition for the data that you import. For your search case, you will be mostly using "text" with Solr factories(filters/tokenizers etc) applied to the text data.

3.How you define the schema depends on the user flow , you will chose. Is your site going to be language neutral and a search for "fem" will show all results from all languages which start with "fem".
Or you are going to let user select the language first. e.g. "French", and then search the term only in the 'fr' field, which would be a cleaner solution in my opinion.